# Invalid Header Name In Flutter HTTP Request

Tags: flutter

I have a login page where i am trying to send a login request to my backend. But I get an Unhandled Exception: Invalid header field name. Here is my submit function

```
submit() async {
var res = await LoginAPI().loginData(
    {'email': _emailController.value, 'password': _passwordController.value});
var body = json.decode(res.body);
print(body);
}
```

Then in my LoginAPI class here is my loginData function that makes the call to the backend

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoginAPI {
  final String _url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/";
  Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};

 loginData(data) async {
 var fullUrl = _url + "v1/users/login";
  return await http.post(
    fullUrl, 
    body: jsonEncode(data),
    headers: headers
    );      
   }
  }
```

Here is my request through postman
[image: Postman request]

[image: Postman request 2]

Here is my response through postman
[image: Response Image]

When I make the same request with Postman i get the response I am supposed to get. What Am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163993/flutter-asp-net-web-api-invalid-header-field-name

Comment: also it would be great if you share response

Comment: I have shared my response and that post did not help me at all.

Comment: You may be encountering a well known server bug, where the server expects a certain case of the header names. `package:http` lower cases all header names, which is perfectly valid but confuses some servers. Confirm with another client (not sure if you can control the header name in postman) with a lower case `content-type`. If you can duplicate the problem, then it's a server issue. You can always just use Dart's `HttpClient` which does not change the case of headers.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks. So i sent a request with postman using lower case content-type and I got the right response back. I guess I will just use dart HttpCLient

Comment: Can you update the question to show the postman request?

Comment: @RichardHeap I have updated the question with the postman request. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to solve the issue. The issue was with my CORS middleware on my server. I just made some changes and it worked fine. So if anyone has this issue just know it has nothing to do with flutter but most probably CORS

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",  "Accept": "application/json",};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks from your postman request that you are just sending form data (not a json encoded body). `package:http` will form encode the body for you (and add the content type header) if you do the following:

```
  return await http.post(
    fullUrl, 
    body: data,
  );
```